# General theory of discriminants

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elliptic-curves, discriminant

I read it in the book *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves* by *Silverman and Tate*:

> If $f(x)$ is a polynomial with leading coefficient 1 in $Z[x]$, then the discriminant of $f(x)$ will be in the ideal $<f(x), f'(x)>$

It says it follows from general theory of discriminant, but what's general theory? Or how to prove it instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discriminant of a polynomial $f$ of degree $n$  and leading coefficient $a_n$ is
$$\operatorname{disc}f=\frac{(-1)^{\tfrac{n(n-1)}2}}{a_n}\operatorname{Res}(f,f').$$
($\operatorname{Res}(f,g)$ denotes the *resultant* of the polynomials $f$ and $g$). Thus it is $0$ if and only if $f$ has a multiple root.

For any polynomials $f,g$, it can be shown there exist polynomials $u,v$ such that
$$\operatorname{Res}(f,g)=uf+vg.$$
Hence the assertion for the discriminant of $f$.